# How to use crpyto in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I am learning NodeJs, and I am trying to implement the crypto library to encrypt and decrpty text,
I am referring the following example -
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ref_crypto.asp

**The code to encrypt is as follows -**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var mykey = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', 'mypassword');
var mystr = mykey.update('abc', 'utf8', 'hex')
mystr += mykey.update.final('hex');

console.log(mystr);
```

**The code to decrypt is as follows -**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var mykey = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-cbc', 'mypassword');
var mystr = mykey.update('34feb914c099df25794bf9ccb85bea72', 'hex', 'utf8')
mystr += mykey.update.final('utf8');

console.log(mystr);
```

The code samples seem to work on their environment,
But I am getting the following error when I try to run the same code on my machine -

```
mystr += mykey.update.final('hex');
                      ^

TypeError: mykey.update.final is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/office/pocs/node-apps/sample-apps/Apps/crypto.js:5:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)
    at startMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:439:3)
```

**Can someone help implement it correctly to encrypt and decrytp text?
What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Check the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_final_outputencoding). Seems like w3schools.com is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update line

```
mystr += mykey.update.final('hex');
```

to

```
mystr += mykey.final("hex");
```

Tried the code according to 
[official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_final_outputencoding)

Comment: Thanks it worked, but is the code deprecated? I am getting the following warning - "(node:25470) [DEP0106] DeprecationWarning: crypto.createCipher is deprecated."

Comment: How can I decrypt this -> const crypto = require('crypto');

const secret = 'abcdefg';
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
                   .update('I love cupcakes')
                   .digest('hex');
console.log(hash);

Comment: createCipher is depreciated, try using createCipheriv